# PHPUnit Database testing without connecting to Database

Tags: php, database, postgresql, unit-testing, phpunit

I am pretty much new to PHPUnit Testing. I have database class which connects to PostgreSQL database and has DML and execute methods for which I want to write test cases.

Is there any way in PHPUnit to run test cases that doesn't rely on having a live database connection? I came to know mock objects in PHPUnit but need some more information regadring how I can achieve my test.

Comment: Look into using the PHPUnit Mock functions https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html to fake the responses so you can then test that your code behaves as it should.

Comment: How about using PHP mock object framework like Mockery. Found it on github https://github.com/padraic/mockery ?

Comment: Mockery could be used to.  You use a mock object to fake the connection and then return what you expect. Mockery will do this.